# How to fix the access_denied_insufficient_permissions when trying to list the users in your Enterprise box account?

Tags: sdk, box

I am using the Box enterprise Python SDK and Java SDK. I have created a service account, and I want to access files in my enterprise from this account using the "As-User" header.

I try to list users with `box_client.users()`. But I keep getting `access_denied_insufficient_permissions`

How do I give my Service Account access to list all users?

Comment: I think this is because I was using an app user input that is a user without permissions to list groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to have the scope set in the app and have it authorized in the enterprise admin console by an admin.

[image]

Comment: After this is done, do you need to get a new refresh token? Does "Manage app users" still supposed to appear?